# update git submodule by n commits

Tags: git, git-submodules

So I know how to update git submodules to the latest master. But as I have not done it in a long time, the latest master is 700+ commits ahead of the version I am using and is by now incompatible with my code. At some point I should update my code, but right now I would like to just update to the newest version that is still compatible with my code. One idea was to update a submodule by e.g. 100 commits and then see if that still works. How would I do that, or is there an even better way (maybe using tags/releases as intermediate steps)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git submodules: Specify a branch/tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777854/git-submodules-specify-a-branch-tag)

Answer (score 0):

Simply `cd` into the submodule directory and invoke `git checkout COMMITISH` to select the commit you want. When you find a version that works for you, you can commit with the reference to that specific submodule commit.